# Error when attempting to boot Centos 7 install from pen drive

Tags: boot, centos

I followed the instructions here:

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey

In an attempt to install Centos 7 in a work laptop which currently only has FreeDOS.

This was the exact command I issued in a computer running Centos 7 and that had an ISO for a Centos7 installation disc.

```
dd if=CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1611.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

The result when attempting to boot is this error:

[image]

What should I do? How do I proceed with the install.

PS: In case its importante I'm using an 8Gb Memory Card with an USB Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what the actual problem is: so here are some troubleshooting tips. Try booting your USB stick in another computer, and see if the Centos Installer loads. If it doesn't work in another computer, you should suspect your USB drive.

In that case either

1. The USB stick is defective - try using a second USB drive to 'copy' the ISO
2. Your 'copy' using `dd` was not successful, you could try again with

`dd BS=4M if=./CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1611.iso of=/dev/sdX oflag=sync`

where the `X` in sdX is the 'letter' corresponding to the block device of the USB drive, probably 'b' given your initial command. You can see all block devices with `lsblk`.

Comment: I downloaded a new version of centos, used dd just like before and this time it worked. So thank you!